How to change theme manually in Mui, PigmentCss, Vite, react-swc with Typescript setup
How to change the theme manually with a simple button click in Vite project with Mui 6, pigmentCss, typescript, react-swc. an example sandbox will help me to understand how things work.
here is my sandbox which i still couldn't find a solution. Pls help. Thanks
sandbox
a simple demo will do. I attach a sample sandbox

When changing the mode (light/dark), the mode needs to save in the app. So if users refresh the browser tab, the mode gets saved.
